# Update SQL table using selection from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-update

I want to update the values of a SQL table based on the value from another table where the two tables have a common ID.

When I run my script it says it work. But when I check the table that should have been updated value it still has the old/original value.

I based my script on an article from this site (how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server) but because SQL is telling be the script ran with no errors and 2 rows where updated I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong.

```sql
UPDATE    Table A
SET       Table A.StatusID = 2
FROM      Table B INNER JOIN
          Table A ON Table B.ID = Table A.ID
WHERE     (Table B.ApprovalState = 2)
```

Comment: Mysql or (MS)sql-server? Please remove unrelated tags

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags for now; you'll need to [edit] the question to readd the correct DBMS tag.

Comment: can  you please post your tables and the expected result.

Comment: SQL server sorry wrong tag

Comment: your sql is not sql ... this query will throw errors - so maybe you check that first

Comment: That syntax, however, isn't valid T-SQL and I'm prettyu sure it isn't valid MySQL either. More likely your attempt to anonymise the query has broken it.

Comment: There are no errors thrown I am in SQL Server Management studio. When I run this script I receive the following, (2 rows affected) Completion time: 2022-08-23T09:55:58.4871378-04:00

Comment: *"There are no errors thrown"* Then the query in your question and the query you are running are not the same. This will error with `Incorrect syntax near keyword 'table'`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be From TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB,ID WHERE     (TableB.ApprovalState = 2)

Comment: Thank you learning, your comment answered my question! I switched the tables and it worked. How do I give you credit for helping me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be write as tis :

```
UPDATE    A
SET       StatusID = 2
FROM      TableB AS B INNER JOIN
          TableA AS A ON B.ID = A.ID
WHERE     B.ApprovalState = 2
```

Comment: Thank you SQLpro you and learning had the same idea and it worked perfectly. very much appreciate your help.